# Prove that all the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ are of the form $n\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Describe all subgroups of the group $\mathbb{Z}$

The subgroups are $\{ 0 \}$, $\mathbb{Z}$ and $n \mathbb{Z} = \{ n k : k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ How to prove it?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: If two coprime integers belong to the same subgroup. such a subgroup is the whole $\mathbb{Z}$ by Bezout's identity.

Answer (score 7):

It is easy to show that $n\mathbb{Z} < \mathbb{Z}$. To show these are all, let $H$ be any subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$, and then we can pick a least element in $H$, as $\mathbb{Z_{\ge 0}}$ is well ordered. Definitely $H$ will always have positive elements too, as it is a subgroup and thus all inverses will be in it (if $k$ is in there , $-k$ will also be). Suppose $n$ is the least positive integer in $H$ then we claim $H= n\mathbb{Z}$.

Clearly $n\mathbb{Z} \subseteq H$

Now, for reverse containment, let $k \in H$ be any element then use division algorithm, i.e. $k=nq+r$ , where $0 \leq r < n$, then $k-nq =r \in H$, which implies $r=0$, so $k=nq \in \mathbb{Z}$, hence $H \subseteq n\mathbb{Z}$, and so $H= n\mathbb{Z}$

Hence proved.

Comment: Why $n\mathbb{Z}\subseteq H$?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, $\{0\}$ is subgroup of $Z$. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $Z$ other than $\{0\}$, then there exist a non-zero
integer $a ∈ H$. Since, $H$ is subgroup, $−a ∈ H$. Hence, $H$ contains atleast one positive integer. By Well ordering
principle, there exist a smallest positive integer $k$ in $H$.

> Claim: $H = kZ$

Since $k ∈ H$ and $H$ is a subgroup implies all integral multiples of $k ∈ H$ which in turn implies that $kZ ⊆ H$. Now,
we show that $H −kZ = φ$ which would imply that $H = kZ$.
If possible, assume $H − kZ ̸\neq φ$ then there exist $x ∈ H −kZ$, then $x$ is not a multiple of $k$. By division algorithm,
there exist integer $q$,$r$ such that $x = kq+r$; $\space0 < r ≤ k−1$, which in turn implies that $x−kq = r ∈ H$, therefore $H$
contains a positive integer $< k$, which is a contradiction as $k$ is the least positive integer in $H$.
Hence, $H −kZ = φ \implies H = kZ$. Therefore, subgroups of $Z$ are $\{0\}$ and $nZ$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).