# Subgroups of the integers

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

Want to show:

Consider the additive group, $\mathbb{Z}$. Show that the subgroups are of the form $n\mathbb{Z}$, for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$

Proof:

Note that for $1\in \mathbb{Z}$, $\langle 1\rangle=\mathbb{Z}$, hence $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ is a cyclic group, and therefore every subgroup is cyclic. So let $H \leq \mathbb{Z}$, that means $H = \langle h\rangle  = \{ nh\mid n\in \mathbb{Z} \}= h \mathbb{Z}$.

Is the proof correct? May I have feedback, please? Every proof I've seen relies on the division algorithm at some point, isn't the above proof, a more direct proof?

Note: I have considered this to be a corollary to theorem, every subgroup of a cyclic subgroup is cyclic.

Comment: A better proof is given at [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1263673/prove-that-all-the-subgroups-of-mathbbz-are-of-the-form-n-mathbbz), without using that subgroups of cyclic groups are cyclic.

Comment: I'm afraid the the proof of the assertion on subgroups of cyclic groups relies on properties of $\mathbf Z$.

Comment: @Bernard what does that say about my proof?

Comment: @DietrichBurde okay, but that doesn't say where my proof fails, may you please elaborate?

Comment: Your proof has a gap right here: "and therefore every subgroup is cyclic". This statement is true. But you have not justified it. In fact, I would say that the justification of this step is the most important part of the proof. So, your proof is incomplete.

Comment: @LeeMosher The proof is provided in the book i'm using, so I felt as though it is unnecessary for me to provide it here. Other than that, does everything else hold? Is the logic correct?